# Is there a limit to the length of metadata values in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

When uploading a file to Google Cloud Storage, there is a custom data field `metadata`.

[Google's example](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/1.0.0/storage/file?method=setMetadata) is fairly short:

```
var metadata = {
  contentType: 'application/x-font-ttf',
  metadata: {
    my: 'custom',
    properties: 'go here'
  }
};

file.setMetadata(metadata, function(err, apiResponse) {});
```

Is there a maximum for how big GCS will allow for the metadata object, should I wish to store manifests of tar and zip files, or a few hundred KB in there?

Comment: You can try, but metadata storage is counted and billed at normal rate anyway.

Comment: The point is to put something in there that lets me know if I want the 3 Gig file or not...

Comment: This is undocumented, and only who tried or the engineers know. Why don't you try putting 3GB in it?

Comment: I don't know offhand what the limit is for metadata, but I wouldn't really advise putting large amounts of data in it. Custom metadata is frequently returned as part of operations like object listing, which could become much slower and more bandwidth heavy if you put a lot of data in there. I would suggest instead creating a related "summary" object and perhaps referencing that object's name in the main object's custom metadata.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the following command to upload set metadata in GCS:

```
$ echo '{"metadata": {"large": "' > body ; tr -dC '[:print:]' < /dev/urandom | tr -d '\\"' | head -c SIZE_OF_METADATA_IN_BYTES >> body ;  echo '"}}' >> body; curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -X PATCH -H "Content-type: application/json" -d @body -o return_body https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/manifest-geode-357/o/empty
```

I Find that above 2097KB header the service returns "HTTP 413 Request Too Large" and metadata is not set. Below that level it is set as expected. If I use more compressible input (e.g. the output of `yes`), I can get more data, but the cut-off is at the same content-length value (which is post-compression). As 2097KB == 2MiB almost exactly, I expect the true limitation is the entire HTTP request must fit in 2MiB.

---

However Brandon's comment is correct: this is not a great idea for a whole catalog of reasons:

1. This will cause you to consume more bandwidth (with associated performance and cost penalty)
2. You won't save any money on storage costs (as metadata is still charged for).
3. It relies on undocumented behaviour which might be changed by Google without any notice.
4. Unlike real object data, there is no resumable-behaviour on upload, so errors hit you worse.
5. There is no checksum to verify integrity during the upload process.
6. It's likely that many client libraries store metadata in-memory rather than on disk or keep multiple copies, so you are more likely to see memory pressure in your application.

Simply storing the manifest in a separate object solves all of these issues. You could store thie *location* of the manifest in the metadata, and get the benefit of both options.

Comment: The letters "ABC" repeated over and over would gzip rather nicely. 1MB of "ABC" put through gzip becomes only 1KB. What happens if the data is a bit more random?

Comment: Using `tr -dC '[:print:]' < /dev/urandom | tr -d '\\"'` to print random printable non-", non-\ chars in place of 'yes' I find the threshold at ........ 2097KB, as predicted.  This is basically exactly 2MiB. Editing answer to reflect this.

Comment: This is good enough for me.  The bounty was placed by someone else, though.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas)

> here is a maximum combined size limit for all custom metadata keys and values of **8 KiB** per object.