# Cloud Storage - metadata part is too large

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We have photo uploading functionality in the app which works for a lot of people, but some people get the following error:

```
"{
    "responseData": "Metadata part is too large."
}
"
```

when trying to upload a file.

I use Google Cloud Storage using FormData() to upload a file through POST using signed policy document.

This is how I issue the policy using nodejs latest cloud storage library (5.18.1):

```
        const gcsClient = new Storage({
            projectId: EnvConfig.gcpProjectId,
            credentials: getGoogleCloudStorageCredentials ()
        });

        const policyOpts = {
            equals: ['$Content-Type', contentType],
            expires: getTodaysDateSecondsAdded(900),
            contentLengthRange: {
                min: 0,
                max: 20000000 // 20MB
            }
        };

        const [{ base64, signature, string }] = await gcsClient
            .bucket(EnvConfig.gcpUploadBucket)
            .file(fileName)
            .getSignedPolicy(policyOpts);
```

and this is how it gets uploaded:

```
    const data = new FormData();

    data.append('policy', policy64);
    data.append('signature', policySignature);
    data.append('file', {uri: sourceUrl, type: contentType});
    data.append('key', fileName);
    data.append('GoogleAccessId', googleAccessId);
    data.append('Content-Type', contentType);

    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
    const source = CancelToken.source();


    try {
          await axios.post(uploadUrl, data);
    } catch (e) {

      if (axios.isCancel(e)) {
        throw new Error(`axios upload image failed due to timeout`);
      }

      throw e;
    }
```

It is confusing to me what metadata part is being referenced to? Are we talking about the object metadata that's part of cloud storage concept? If yes, I have no control over it, I don't add any metadata anywhere? Or are we talking about the image metadata itself?

Is this just a bad error and it actually means that file size is too large?

According to this:

"There is a maximum combined size limit for all custom metadata keys and values of 8 KiB per object."  - https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas

So my current hypothesis is that somewhere a magic object metadata is generated that is over 8KB, is there some undocumented part of logic in cloud storage that automatically pulls custom metadata from POST request?

I saw bunch of potential duplicates but there's no answer out there:

[Uploading File to GCS - Metadata part is too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197800/uploading-file-to-gcs-metadata-part-is-too-large)

[Is there a limit to the length of metadata values in Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43222150/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-metadata-values-in-google-cloud-storage)

Comment: Pardon me, I'm a little new to axios, so I'm wondering why you're using FormData() over a simple json object?

Comment: @fabc it is my understanding that FormData is the simplest way to upload a file that is stored on your phone by just providing the file path where it resides, without loading it into memory in our app. This allows the JS/OS to take care of loading/chunking the file as it wants to, otherwise if we load the large file ourselves to be posted through JSON we'll get out of memory exceptions.

Comment: Is there better way to do this? Note FormData is not axios concept as such, it is JS concept that is supported in nodejs as well browser.  It is just using HTML forms: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-forms you can submit the FormData() object with Ajax requests: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out after months of debugging,

basically when attaching file to form data, you also need to specify name: otherwise it will fail for bigger files >4MB+.

before (kept failing):

```
data.append('file', { uri: assetUri, type: contentType});
```

after:

```
data.append('file', { uri: assetUri, type: contentType, name: 'dummy.jpg' });
```

If you read react-native source code, you'll see the "name" will force emiting filename= in the multipart/formdata request

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225060183

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks for your months of debugging, it saved me time  I can't believe the fix was this easy: `data.append('file', fileBuffer, 'dummy.jpg')`

Comment: You saved my day. Erti-Chris Eelmaa

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you are passing in the file:

```js
    data.append('file', {uri: sourceUrl, type: contentType});
```

This is not actually setting a file as you intended. I believe the file is being passed as regular form data instead of a separate part in the multipart/form-data upload, and so is exceeding a limit. This format of call does not appear in the [FormData doc you linked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).

Instead, try actually creating a File object to pass:

```js
    data.append('file', f /*an instance of File or Blob*/);
```

Comment: you are right, I'll have to clarify what this construct is: this is the react native's way to append file to formdata, there is no other way to do it by default, as react native does not have File() or Blob() constructs. 

That said, I tried react-native-fetch-blob library that allows me to use "Blob" polyfill, and it actually works now. It is real shame though that we had to include new library for this, also am unclear where the diff comes from as I've debugged using Charles proxy and found absolutely no differences in the requests, but one works and other doesn't.

Comment: It looks like react-native's FormData is actually a bit different from the standard FormData, and is for react-native's own implementation of XMLHttpRequest. My guess is react-native's XHR has special handling for the Object{uri,type} format. Is it possible you're accidentally using a browser's own XHR instead of the react provided one?

Comment: react native has it's own implementation as you said, there is no "browsers own XHR" in react native, the XHR mechanism is implemented by react native. That said, I have been in world of pain regarding this issue, while I got it fixed by using react-native-blob-util library, it caused new issues which are not related to google cloud as such, but the bottom line is, it is extremely difficult to use cloud storage on react native, I would recommend bubbling it up with support team and disabling this 2MB limit for POST requests, which could be the easiest solution.

Comment: I'd be also up for raising this issue in react-native github however without further internal details I have no idea what should I write there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
    let blob = new Blob([fs.readFileSync("route/to/file")]);
    formData.append('file', blob, 'filename.txt');
```

Or directly if you have the content:

```js
    let blob = new Blob(["Content to upload"], { type: 'text/plain' });
    formData.append('file', blob, 'filename.txt');
```